# Converting pscustomobject into Json format

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have  sample Json format that I am currently trying to code using powershell and convert it to Json format using PScustomobject, however I am having a hard time since the DBdetails count will depend on an array that I am retrieving. What is wrong with my logic?

```
$dbcountall = 1
foreach ($alldblist in $dblist)
{  
if($dbcountall -eq 1)
{
    $name = $alldblist.name
    $dbdetailsname = "DBDetails" + $dbcountall
    $dbpiece = [pscustomobject]@{ 
    SourceType = "$name"
    TargetType = "$name"
    }
    $alldb += [pscustomobject]@{ 
    DataBasesCount = $dblist.count
    $dbdetailsname = $dbpiece
    }
}
else
{
    $name = $alldblist.name
    $dbdetailsname = "DBDetails" + $dbcountall
        $dbpiece = [pscustomobject]@{ 
        SourceType = "$name"
        TargetType = "$name"
        }
    $alldb += [pscustomobject]@{ 
    $dbdetailsname = $dbpiece
    }
}
$dbcountall++
}

##Output is
"Databases":  [
                                   {
                                       "DatabasesCount":  "4",
                                       "DBDetails1":  {
                                                          "Source":  "SampleDB1",
                                                          "Target":  "SampleDB1"
                                                      }
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "DBDetails2":  {
                                                          "Source":  "SampleDB2",
                                                          "Target":  "SampleDB2"
                                                      }
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "DBDetails3":  {
                                                          "Source":  "testdatabase",
                                                          "Target":  "testdatabase"
                                                      }
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "DBDetails4":  {
                                                          "Source":  "Testdatabase_backup_10GB",
                                                          "Target":  "Testdatabase_backup_10GB"
                                                      }
                                   }
                               ],
```

Result should look like this and from above, its having an additional bracketing.

```
"Databases": [
     {
      "DatabasesCount": "3",
      "DBDetails1": {
        "Source": "db1",
        "Target": "db1"
      },
      "DBDetails2": {
        "Source": "db2",
        "Target": "db2"
      },
      "DBDetails3": {
        "Source": "db3",
        "Target": "db3"
      }

    }
  ],
```

Comment: Can you please higglight the discrepancy

Comment: `$alldb` should be one object with many properties, but not an array where each object have only one (or two) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating one object per database, create one object, then add properties for each database.

```
$DatabaseInfo = [pscustomobject]@{
    DatabasesCount = $dblist.count
}
For($i=1;$i -le $dblist.count;$i++){
    $DBObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        Source = $dblist[$i-1].Name
        Target = $dblist[$i-1].Name
    }
    $DatabaseInfo | Add-Member "DBDetails$i" $DBObject
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of only using if statement for that and not aware of this method. Tried it and it worked. Thanks a lot!